Не работает форматирование текста в консоли
Я делаю цветной вывод в консоль python-скрипта, после чего преобразую в .exe. На компьютере, на котором этот файл был создан, он работает нормально (в любой папке), а на другом - нет (проверял просто на другом компьютере и в песочнице, и там, и там мимо). Что нужно сделать, чтобы везде было нормально?
Ожидаемый вывод (на первом ПК): 
Получаемый вывод (на втором ПК и в песочнице): 
P.S. - я заметил, что консоли разные. Почему?

Цветной вывод использует escape-последовательности, которые НЕ поддерживаются всеми консолями.

В таком случае как можно сделать, чтобы при запуске .exe приложения запускалась консоль, которая поддерживает ANSI? Я, если что, никакие уникальные консоли не ставил, обе - обычные консоли windows, только почему-то разные.

@onix на первом скриншоте windows terminal, который необходимо устанавливать из Windows Store, обычно её рекомендуют установить для работы с подсистемой wsl. На втором же скриншоте обычная cmd.exe, самая стандартная.

@Falchio, спасибо. Видимо, все же устанавливал, просто забыл :)

Проблема не в програме, а в настройках консоли на конкретном компьютере. Если речь идет про Windows 10, то настройки можно изменить через редактирование реестра.
Например, можно попробовать создать в HKCU\Console ключ с именем VirtualTerminalLevel, типа DWORD и значением 0x1.
Но это, возможно, решит проблему на конкретном компьютере. Т.е. решение не универсальное. Вероятно вам следует отказаться от использования цветом и других escape последовательностей в вашей программе. Если же отказаться нельзя, то можно подумать в сторону какого-нибудь инсталятора для вашего приложения. Который при установке будет вносить изменения в настройки консоли.
Как вариант, можно попробовать использовать модуль colorama, который вроде бы как позволяет использовать цвета при выводе в консоле. И при этом обеспечивает работоспособность в различных операционных системах.

Моя программа буквально для пары человек, так что мне такие заморочки ни к чему) Но в других случаях это, кажется, поможет, возможно, даже мне в будущем пригодится. Так что спасибо

Есть ещё модуль Rich, там тоже цветное всякое рисует, не знаю правда насколько совместимое.
